# Optimally access an SQLAlchemy model paramater n number of relationships away

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The title of the question may be confusing, but I believe I have described the issue below.

I have various declarative "test type" models that I have built with SQLAlchemy. Each "test type" model is associated with a piece of "equipment" that sits on a "location". Therefore, each test type has a "location.name" parameter that is located a varying number of relationships away from the actual test model. I need this "location.name" value to be associated with each "test" object.

The way I have it set up now emits a ton of SQL when querying the tests. I imagine this is because of the relationship cascade. I display all tests in a single table and I would like to be able to somehow filter the tests based on the location they are associated with.

This model configuration is new to me and I am do not know how to interact with it using raw `SQL`, I only know how to work with the models.

I am wondering what the optimal way to get a particular test instance's location's name parameter. Notice that `location.name` is returned on each test's `get_json()` function, although I am hoping there is a better way that will emit less SQL and be simpeler when it comes to filtering all test types.

Hopefully the below model definitions make this clear

```
class Location(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('location_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    ...


class EquipmentFoo(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'equipmentfoos'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('equipmentfoo_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('locations.id'))
    location = relationship('Location', backref='equipmentfoos')
    footests = relationship('FooTest', backref='equipmentfoo')
    ...


class EquipmentBar(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'equipmentbars'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('equipmentbar_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    equipmentfoo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('equipmentfoos.id'))
    equipmentfoo = relationship('EquipmentFoo', backref='equipmentbars')
    bartests = relationship('BarTest', backref='equipmentbar')
    ...


class EquipmentZab(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'equipmentzabs'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('equipmentzab_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    equipmentbar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('equipmentbars.id'))
    equipmentbar = relationship('EquipmentBar', backref='equipmentzabs')
    zabtests = relationship('ZabTest', backref='equipmentzab')
    ...
```

So there are the equipment models and how they relate to a location. Also included are their relationships to their respective tests below.

```
class HasId(object):
    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column('id', Integer, Sequence('test_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    @declared_attr
    def status(cls):
        return Column('status', String(50))
    ...


class TestParent(HasId, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tests'
    discriminator = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}
    ...
    def parent_json(self):
        return {'id': self.id,
                'status': self.status,
                ...
                }         


class FooTest(TestParent):
    __tablename__ = 'footests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'footests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True) cascade='save-update, merge')
    pressure_start = Column(Float)
    ...
    def get_json():
        my_json = {'location': self.equipmentfoo.location.name,
                   'pressure_start': self.pressure_start,
                   ...
                   }
        parent_json = super(FooTest, self).parent_json()
        my_json.update(parent_json)
        return my_json


class BarTest(TestParent):
    __tablename__ = 'bartests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'bartests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True) cascade='save-update, merge')
    hatch_value = Column(Boolean)
    ...
    def get_json():
        my_json = {'location': self.equipmentbar.equipmentfoo.location.name,
                   'hatch_value': self.hatch_value,
                   ...
                   }
        parent_json = super(BarTest, self).parent_json()
        my_json.update(parent_json)
        return my_json


class ZabTest(TestParent):
    __tablename__ = 'zabtests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'zabtests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True) cascade='save-update, merge')
    safety_check = Column(Boolean)
    ...
    def get_json():
        my_json = {'location': self.equipmentzab.equipmentbar.equipmentfoo.location.name,
                   'safety_check': self.hatch_value,
                   ...
                   }
        parent_json = super(ZabTest, self).parent_json()
        my_json.update(parent_json)
        return my_json
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, relationships are not loaded. That means the first time you access a relationship a query is emitted to fetch the data, which in turn doesn't load *its* relationships. For your scenario, for `n` `ZabTest` instances, it emits `4n` queries to get the name of the location.

The general approach to making many small operations efficient is through batching, which combines the overhead of many operations into one. The way to do this in SQL is to query multiple rows at once instead of one row at a time. SQLAlchemy exposes this ability through [eager loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-loader-strategies-lazy-loading-eager-loading):

```
session.query(ZabTest).options(
    joinedload(ZabTest.equipmentzab)
    .joinedload(EquipmentZab.equipmentbar)
    .joinedload(EquipmentBar.equipmentfoo)
    .joinedload(EquipmentFoo.location))
```

What this accomplishes is it populates the entire chain of `self.equipmentbar.equipmentfoo.location.name`, including `ZabTest` itself, *in a single query*.

Alternatively, you can configure SQLAlchemy to *always* eager load:

```
zabtests = relationship('ZabTest', backref=backref('equipmentzab', lazy="joined"))
```

Be forewarned: since you are also using inheritance, the eager loading syntax may get hairy. Always check the emitted SQL to make sure you are joining things in correctly.

Comment: Sometimes you need to explicitly join in order to filter.  If that is the case, you should use `contains_eager`, otherwise sqlalchemy will make anonymous joins for the relationships as well.